# Script to check if mounts are mounted or not

Tags: bash, shell

I came across this script here,

```
   #!/bin/bash

A=``awk '{print $2}' /etc/fstab | grep -i "^/" | egrep -v '/etc/fstab|proc|sys|shm|pts`'`

`for i in $A; do grep "$i" /proc/mounts > /dev/null`

`if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $i "TRUE"
else
    echo $i "FALSE"
fi
done`
```

this give me this error

```
./mount.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./mount.sh: line 5: ``for i in $A; do'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you copied and pasted the script you got some extra ` marks (that's a backquote in case it doesn't come out as expected).

```
#!/bin/bash

A=`awk '{print $2}' /etc/fstab | grep -i "^/" | egrep -v '/etc/fstab|proc|sys|shm|pts'`

for i in $A; do grep "$i" /proc/mounts > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $i "TRUE"
    else
        echo $i "FALSE"
    fi
done
```

Try that instead.

Comment: Also instead of grepping through /proc/mounts use `mountpoint` command. I'd say it is more robust then manual handling of such stuff.

Answer (score -1):

```
 grep -vE "pts|proc|sys|shm|^#|^$" /etc/fstab| while read -r a b c d e ;do echo $b $(grep -q ^$a\ $b /proc/mounts && echo TRUE || echo FALSE) ;done
```